# How to Decode the returns of Aggregate()

Tags: mongodb, go

I'm trying to do a query in MongoDB, just like the group by in SQL. So I use the Aggregate() API, to find all the unique _id(MarketType+Symbol).

And the Aggregate() runs successful, but when I decode the return values, I got nothing. Aggregate() return type is the same as Find(), and I decode in this way when Find() is useful. Why it can't work when I Aggregate().

```
type MarketSymbol struct {
    MarketType  string  `json:"Market,omitempty" bson:"MarketType"`
    Symbol      string  `json:"Symbol,omitempty" bson:"Symbol"`
}

func GetSymbol() {
    pipeline := bson.M {
        "$group"    :    
        bson.M{"_id":bson.M{"MarketType":"$MarketType","Symbol":"$Symbol"}},
    }
    cur,err := mongoSt.Collection.Aggregate(context.TODO(), []bson.M{pipeline})
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Aggregate Error:", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Aggregate Success!")    //this line works
    }
    var results []MarketSymbol
    count := 1

    for cur.Next(context.TODO()) {
        var elem MarketSymbol
        err := cur.Decode(&elem)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("[count]=%d   Decode Error\n", count)
            count++
            continue
        }
        fmt.Printf("[count]=%d, [MarketType]:%s , [Symbol]:%s\n", count, elem.MarketType, elem.Symbol)    //this line works,but value is nil
        count++
        results = append(results, elem)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it. I also tried to use *_id* to save the Decode value before, but failed. So I thought it doesn't work. But it's right, what actually caused the error is I gave a wrong type of *MarketType*, it should be int32 but I gave it a string. So...

Anyway, the problem solved, here is the code.

```
type ID struct {
    Id  MarketSymbol    `json:"ID,omitempty" bson:"_id"`
}

type MarketSymbol struct {
    MarketType  int32   `json:"Market,omitempty" bson:"MarketType"`
    Symbol      string  `json:"Symbol,omitempty" bson:"Symbol"`
}

func GetSymbol{
    pipeline := bson.M {
        "$group"    :   bson.M{"_id":bson.M{"MarketType":"$MarketType","Symbol":"$Symbol"}},
    }

    cur,err := mongoSt.Collection.Aggregate(context.TODO(), []bson.M{pipeline})
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Aggregate Error:", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Aggregate Success!")
    }

    var results []ID
    count := 1

    for cur.Next(context.TODO()) {
        var elem ID
        err := cur.Decode(&elem)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("[count]=%d   Decode Error\n", count)
            count++
            continue
        }
        fmt.Printf("[count]=%d, [MarketType]:%d , [Symbol]:%s\n", count, elem.Id.MarketType, elem.Id.Symbol)
        count++
        results = append(results, elem)
    }
}
```